# Why do I get those empty strings when using re.split() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I define a split function as `lambda x: re.split('[(|)|.]', x)`, and when I applied this function to my original strings, it always generates some empty strings. For example:

When applied to string:

```
(Type).(Terrorist organization)AND(Involved in attacks).(nine-eleven)
```

The result is:

```
['', 'Type', '', '', 'Terrorist organization', 'AND', 'Involved in attacks', '', '', 'nine-eleven', '']
```

I know I can simply remove those empty strings manually, but is there any smart way to get rid of them?

Comment: That depends on what you want. What Output do wish to get?

Comment: Why do you have `|` multiple times in the `[]` character set?

Comment: Are you trying to capture characters within pairs of parentheses? The use of square brackets `[..]` means match any character inside. You can’t use capture groups inside them. `[().]` will match the literal characters present.

Comment: you could filter empty strings afterwards with a post processing listcomp

Comment: Each individual character (`(`, `|`, `)`, `.`) inside the square brackets is considered a separate delimiter.

Comment: try this `re.split('[().]+', s)`. There are still blanks at start & end but you can filter them out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grab as many separators as you can with `+` instead of only one:

```
re.split('[().]+', s)
```

unfortunately, this doesn't suffice as `re.split` notoriously yields empty strings at start & end of the string:

```
['', 'Type', 'Terrorist organization', 'AND', 'Involved in attacks', 'nine-eleven', '']
```

but you can filter them out by using post processing:

```
[x for x in re.split('[().]+', s) if x]
```

On the other hand, you could revert the regex and use `re.findall` to match as much non-separators as possible:

```
re.findall('[^().]+', s)
```

this directly yields:

```
['Type', 'Terrorist organization', 'AND', 'Involved in attacks', 'nine-eleven']
```

Answer (score 1):

The regexp matches `)`, `.`, and `(` individually. Since these are next to each other in the input, there's an empty string between them, so the result contains those empty strings.

If you want to treat a sequence of delimiters as a single delimiter, add a `+` quantifier to the regexp so it matches them as a sequence.

```
re.split('[|().]+', x)
```

The empty string at the beginning is because of the empty string before the first `(`. Similarly, the empty string at the end is from the empty string in the input after the last `)`. I don't think there's a simple way to prevent these, just remove them from the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can `filter`:

```
filter(lambda x: x, re.split('[().]+', s))
```

Test:

```
import re
s = '(Type).(Terrorist organization)AND(Involved in attacks).(nine-eleven)'
print(list(filter(None, re.split('[().]+', s))))
```

Result:

> ['Type', 'Terrorist organization', 'AND', 'Involved in attacks', 'nine-eleven']

Comment: `filter(lambda x: x,` is slightly redundant. You can write `filter(None,`